# VBA web scraping - assigning data to correct rows when some data is missing

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Macro below was supposed to fill search parameters on a website and scrape data from results - 131 pages, usually 5 rows of data each page. For testing I commented out the loop, so it only does 1 page.

The following data columns are filled in Excel worksheet: Company Name, Contact Name, Contact Email, Location, Phone (BH), Mobile, Services.

I have a problem only with Phone (BH) and Mobile. The reason is that companies sometimes only have Phone (BH) or Mobile, not both.

The way I loop (5 company names, then 5 contact names etc.) requires all data to be detected, else I don't know what row should this data be in.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim htmlele As IHTMLElement
Dim Link As String
Dim ie As Object
Dim page As Integer
Dim companyresult As Long, nameresult As Long, emailresult As Long, locationresult As Long, servicesresult As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Link = "http://bdav.org.au/find"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate Link
'ie.Visible = True

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If htmlele.Name = "postcode" Then htmlele.Value = "3000"
Next htmlele

For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If htmlele.Name = "dist" Then htmlele.Value = "99"
Next htmlele

For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If htmlele.Type = "submit" Then htmlele.Click
Next htmlele

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

'Do

    page = page + 1
    Link = "http://bdav.org.au/find/" & page

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
        DoEvents
    Loop

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("results")
        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("h2")
            companyresult = companyresult + 1
            .Range("a" & companyresult + 1).Value = htmlele.innerHTML
        Next htmlele

        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

            If Left(htmlele.href, 7) = "mailto:" Then
                nameresult = nameresult + 1
                .Range("b" & nameresult + 1).Value = htmlele.innerHTML
            End If
        Next htmlele

        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

            If Left(htmlele.href, 7) = "mailto:" Then
                emailresult = emailresult + 1
                .Range("c" & emailresult + 1).Value = Mid(htmlele.href, 8)
            End If

        Next htmlele


        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("label")

            If htmlele.innerHTML = "Location:" Then
                locationresult = locationresult + 1
                .Range("d" & locationresult + 1).Value = htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML
            End If

        Next htmlele

           For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("label")

            If htmlele.innerHTML = "Services:" Then
                servicesresult = servicesresult + 1
                If Right(htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML, 4) = "<br>" Then
                    htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML = Left(htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML, Len(htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML) - 4)
                End If
                .Range("g" & servicesresult + 1).Value = Replace(htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML, "<br>", vbLf)
            End If

        Next htmlele


    End With

'Loop

ie.Quit

Set ie = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with a cleaner approach than I tried before, with just 1 loop through label tag elements collection. I take a row number based on location label appearance (this label always appears for a company). If any other label for the company is missing, it will not be put in this row.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim htmlele As IHTMLElement
Dim Link As String
Dim ie As Object
Dim page As Integer
Dim companyresult As Long, nameresult As Long, emailresult As Long, labelresult As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Link = "http://bdav.org.au/find"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate Link
'ie.Visible = True

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If htmlele.Name = "postcode" Then htmlele.Value = "3000"
Next htmlele

For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If htmlele.Name = "dist" Then htmlele.Value = "99"
Next htmlele

For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If htmlele.Type = "submit" Then htmlele.Click
Next htmlele

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

Do

    page = page + 1
    Link = "http://bdav.org.au/find/" & page

    ie.Navigate Link

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And ie.Busy = False
        DoEvents
    Loop

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("results")
        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("h2")
            companyresult = companyresult + 1
            .Range("a" & companyresult + 1).Value = htmlele.innerHTML
        Next htmlele

        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

            If Left(htmlele.href, 7) = "mailto:" Then
                nameresult = nameresult + 1
                .Range("b" & nameresult + 1).Value = htmlele.innerHTML
            End If
        Next htmlele

        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

            If Left(htmlele.href, 7) = "mailto:" Then
                emailresult = emailresult + 1
                .Range("c" & emailresult + 1).Value = Mid(htmlele.href, 8)
            End If

        Next htmlele

        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("label")

            If htmlele.innerHTML = "Location:" Then
                labelresult = labelresult + 1
                .Range("d" & labelresult + 1).Value = htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML
            ElseIf htmlele.innerHTML = "Phone (BH):" Then
                .Range("e" & labelresult + 1).Value = htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML
            ElseIf htmlele.innerHTML = "Mobile:" Then
                .Range("f" & labelresult + 1).Value = htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML
            ElseIf htmlele.innerHTML = "Services:" Then
                If Right(htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML, 4) = "<br>" Then
                    htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML = Left(htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML, Len(htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML) - 4)
                End If
                .Range("g" & labelresult + 1).Value = Replace(htmlele.NextSibling.innerHTML, "<br>", vbLf)
            End If

        Next htmlele

    End With

Loop

ie.Quit

Set ie = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider going ahead and parsing for *Phone* and *Mobile* data assuming they exist on page, and then run a conditional, error handle to account for potential non-existence. Specifically, the error handle will use `Resume Next` (continue on after problem line) for `Error 91` for *Object variable not set*.

As for aligning to rows, try using a different iterator as `phoneresult = phoneresult + 1` will not be reliable if they are randomly missing. So use `servicesresult` or whatever always present node is sibling to *Phone* or *Mobile*. Below is not exact code but included to demonstrate concept.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error Goto ErrHandle
        '...    
        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("Phone")
            If htmlele.innerHTML = "Phone (BH):" Then
                '...other needed code
                .Range("h" & servicesresult + 1).Value = htmlele.innerHTML
            End If    
        Next htmlele

        For Each htmlele In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("Mobile")
            If htmlele.innerHTML = "Mobile:" Then
                '...other needed code
                .Range("i" & servicesresult + 1).Value = htmlele.innerHTML
            End If    
        Next htmlele
        '...
        Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    ' MISSING NODE ERROR
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        Resume Next
    ' ALL OTHER ERRORS
    Else:
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to make this solution work, there was no error 91 generated for macro. I found a solution however, which I post here.